# Find the projection of the vector onto subspace W.

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

I cannot find the exact way to do this.... W is an orthogonal basis...

w ={{1,2,2,4},{4,-2,8,-4},{0,0,0,0}}

vector v = {7,2,2,1}

Anyone know how to project v onto w?

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559), 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773) and 
[here](/help/notation).

Comment: You cannot have the zero vector in a "basis" or in a linearly independent set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So your subspace is $\operatorname{span}{W} = \operatorname{span}\{(1,2,2,4),(4,-2,8,-4),(0,0,0,0)\} = \operatorname{span}\{(1,2,2,4),(4,-2,8,-4)\}$.  Do you see why I can leave off the zero vector?

The projection of a vector onto a subspace will be a vector, denoted $\operatorname{proj}_{W}(\mathbf v)$ or $\mathbf v_{\|}$, of the same size as $\mathbf v$ which has the property $\mathbf v = \mathbf v_{\|} + \mathbf v_{\bot}$, where $\mathbf v_{\|} \in \operatorname{span}{W}$ and $\langle \mathbf v_{\bot}, \mathbf x\rangle = 0$ for every $\mathbf x \in \operatorname{span}W$.

Because your set is orthogonal, we could use the projection formula $\operatorname{proj}_{W}(\mathbf v) = \dfrac {\langle \mathbf v,\ (1,2,2,4)\rangle}{\|(1,2,2,4)\|^2}(1,2,2,4) + \dfrac {\langle \mathbf v,\ (4,-2,8,-4)\rangle}{\|(4,-2,8,-4)\|^2}(4,-2,8,-4)$.

Note that this formula only works if the basis is orthogonal.  So in general if it isn't, you'll need to use Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization to get an orthogonal basis set for your subspace.

Comment: so its v dot the first vector over the magnitude of the first vector times first vector, then v dot second vector over magnitude of second vector times 2nd vector ?? does this look right?

Comment: Sorry I just edited just to confirm, does my previous comment look correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.  If you're used to the notation $\mathbf v \cdot \mathbf w$, then that's the same as $\langle \mathbf v, \mathbf w\rangle$.

Comment: Sweet. Thanks! Check marked

Answer (score 0):

If V is a subspace of Rn with orthonormal basis $\mathbf u_1$, $\mathbf u_2...\mathbf u_m$, then projection of $\mathbf x$ onto V is

$(\vec{\mathbf u_1}\cdot\mathbf x)\mathbf u_1$ + $(\vec{\mathbf u_2}\cdot\mathbf x)\mathbf u_2$ +···+$(\vec{\mathbf u_m}\cdot\mathbf x)\mathbf u_m$

Use this to calculate the projection of v onto w, where w is the orthonormal basis, m=3 and and the v you gave = x.

Source: http://isites.harvard.edu/fs/docs/icb.topic138287.files/Lesson13_-_Orthogonal_Bases_and_Projections_slides.pdf

Comment: so the project ends up being just a 4x1 vector?

Comment: @user1990406 The projection of $\mathbf v$ is the same type of object as $\mathbf v$.  Also you should notice that to use Gabriel's method, you'll need to first normalize your subspace vectors.

Comment: thanks man... appreciate it

Comment: The link to `isites.harvard.edu` is broken. I'm also unable to find any copy saved on the Wayback Machine.